# Why does adding an extra row in my table in latex break it?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am learning Latex and have a frustrating issue using overleaf. It's fairly simple I have this table:

```
    \begin{table}[b]
    \caption{This is an example table.}    
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \hline
        Year & Maximum Temperature (°C) & Semibalanus balanoides & Mytilus edulis \\  
        \hline
        2003 & 14.8 & 67.1 & 172.83\\ 
        2004 & 14.5 & 68.73 & 62.83\\
        2005 & 15.1 & 21.67 & 22.25\\
        2006 & 15.9 & 189.92 & 16.2\\
        2007 & 14.7 & 9.83 & 32.25\\
        2008 & 15.7 & 23.92 & 35.33\\
        2011 & 15.8 & 66.5 & 20.17\\
        2012 & 16.8 & 76.92 & 12.42\\
        2013 & 15.8 & 6.18 & 32.58\\
        2014 & 16.2 & 18.75 & 15.42\\
        2015 & 15.9 & 69.82 & 20.92\\
        2016 & 16.6 & 7.58 & 3.92\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:1}
    \end{table}
```

I get a nice-looking table. However adding one more row like this:

```
    \begin{table}[b]
    \caption{This is an example table.}    
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \hline
        Year & Maximum Temperature (°C) & Semibalanus balanoides & Mytilus edulis \\  
        \hline
        2003 & 14.8 & 67.1 & 172.83\\ 
        2004 & 14.5 & 68.73 & 62.83\\
        2005 & 15.1 & 21.67 & 22.25\\
        2006 & 15.9 & 189.92 & 16.2\\
        2007 & 14.7 & 9.83 & 32.25\\
        2008 & 15.7 & 23.92 & 35.33\\
        2011 & 15.8 & 66.5 & 20.17\\
        2012 & 16.8 & 76.92 & 12.42\\
        2013 & 15.8 & 6.18 & 32.58\\
        2014 & 16.2 & 18.75 & 15.42\\
        2015 & 15.9 & 69.82 & 20.92\\
        2016 & 16.6 & 7.58 & 3.92\\
        2017 & 15 & 11.67 & 18.25\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:1}
    \end{table}
```

I get nothing compiled at all?

Comment: You can try changing the last row to `2017 & 15.0 & 11.67 & 18.25\\`. The only thing that seems different with it is that it has an integer in the second column.

Comment: This worked. I don't really understand why it worked but I can at least continue on. Thanks

Comment: It looks fine to me.  If I put `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` before that, and `\end{document}` after it, it compiles fine.  Do you have a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) which illustrates the problem?

Comment: There is definitely something amiss with my document. The compiled table is not when I put it but rather at the end. I will work on a MWE thanks

Comment: Oh, if the problem is that the table is _moving_, that's different. A `{table}`, like a `{figure}`, _floats_ – that is, it moves from where it is in the source, to a ‘better’ location, for example at the top of the next page.  If you add a line, then you make the table longer, and that might mean that the calculation of where ‘better’ is, is different.

Comment: For example, if I put `\documentclass{article}\begin{document} Text before.` before your example, and `Text after.\end{document}` after it, I get a two-page document, with ‘Text before. Text after.’ on on page, and the figure floated to the top of the second page.  This is intended behaviour, and what is supposed to happen to tables and figures in properly typset texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I suggest to use the `siunitx` package, which will nicely align all the numbers for you
- to give latex more freedom to find the best possible place, use `[htbp]` as floating specifier instead of restricting it to only the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{This is an example table.}    
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=2.1]
  S[table-format=3.2]
  S[table-format=3.2]
  @{}
}
    \toprule
    {Year} & {Maximum Temperature (°C)} & {Semibalanus balanoides} & {Mytilus edulis} \\  
    \midrule
    2003 & 14.8 & 67.1 & 172.83\\ 
    2004 & 14.5 & 68.73 & 62.83\\
    2005 & 15.1 & 21.67 & 22.25\\
    2006 & 15.9 & 189.92 & 16.2\\
    2007 & 14.7 & 9.83 & 32.25\\
    2008 & 15.7 & 23.92 & 35.33\\
    2011 & 15.8 & 66.5 & 20.17\\
    2012 & 16.8 & 76.92 & 12.42\\
    2013 & 15.8 & 6.18 & 32.58\\
    2014 & 16.2 & 18.75 & 15.42\\
    2015 & 15.9 & 69.82 & 20.92\\
    2016 & 16.6 & 7.58 & 3.92\\
    2017 & 15 & 11.67 & 18.25\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]